# How to fix curl request return weird error PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape A website, when I send a curl request, it returns the following:

```
Error :: An Error Was Encountered The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

but when I send the request with Postman or I enter it with my browser it returns normal page. so now I believe the problem is in my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

is there any solution?

[my url](https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B2)

Comment: Since it complains about the URI, it would help if you shared that as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/وصفات-الخبز

Comment: Please click [edit] under the question, and make sure all relevant details are included there for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the URL.

Try `urlencode()` function.
If that didn't work use this custom function

```
  function encode_url(string $string)
    {
        $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
        $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
        return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urlencode($string));
    }
```

I've tested it and this is the results
`https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B2`

here's the sandbox URL http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e67e3e386e85b52ddee4e2d651b70ff6228e4a6d

[image]

Comment: no not working, it will not work with both functions, since it is not an URL it returned (aHR0cHM6Ly9raXRjaGVuLnNheWlkYXR5Lm5ldC/ZiNi12YHYp9iqLdin2YTYrtio2LI)

Comment: php has native support for urlencoding, check https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @hanshenrik true, but sometimes it doesn't get it right. Like in this case. If you encode it natively then this is the output : https%3A%2F%2Fkitchen.sayidaty.net%2F%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B2  It even encodes the colon and the slash.

Comment: @Jwan thank you for your answer but I actually solved my problem by `$url = "https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/" . urlencode(str_replace("https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/","",$_GET['url'])) ;`

Comment: But that is a bad idea. If you are going to work with OOP, then I highly recommend using my method. So in the future if you have other links so that you don't have to go the code and change it every time you want to make a request to specify URL.

Answer (score 0):

i voted to close this question as "needs debugging details", because i need to see the exact code you're using to get the error. i can **GUESS** that the code is

```php
<?php
$url = 'https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/وصفات-الخبز';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

but because you didn't share the goddamn code, i have to guess, which is a goddamn unnecessary waste of my time, all because you didn't share the goddamn code.

anyway, if i guessed correctly, then the problem is that your url is not properly urlencoded, in which case you can try to urlencode it in php

```
<?php

$url = 'https://kitchen.sayidaty.net/وصفات-الخبز';
$path = substr(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_PATH),strlen("/"));
$url = substr($url, 0, -(strlen($path))). urlencode($path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
return curl_exec($ch);
```

but who the f knows, you didn't share the code needed to reproduce the error, after all.

Comment: lol, sorry for my impatience, I thought you don't need the URL, though my issue was solved. thank you for your answer.